# How to change the background color of ion-header in ionic 2?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

How to change the header color? I tried below but didn't succeeded

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar danger>
    <ion-title>TITLE</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

My variable.scss is:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222
);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can change it globally if you want to in your `variables.scss` under/in the theme folder:

```
$toolbar-background: blue;
```

**For all the reference Ionic SASS Variables to override follow this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)**

Comment: That really helpful! Thanks

Comment: @Pawan when you have set it globally but then you want one page/component with different color, you can put this in its `.scss` file 
`.toolbar-background {
        background-color: #5381A7 !important; 
      }`

Comment: But what is the need of this
On setting it globally the color is changing..
can u please explain?

Comment: I just added an info... the global works fine for all the pages/components, but only if one page you need a different color for the header, so you just overwirte it by adding what I wrote in the comment above ,if the need arises thats all... otherwise, changing it globally does the trick alright

Comment: okey i got it Thnku

Comment: You also can see all possible Ionic variables in : http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/

Comment: Is it just me who sees a small [fouc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) when opening menu with such styling?

Answer (score 17):

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="color3">
    <ion-title></ion-title>
  </ion-navbar> 
</ion-header>
```

> you can set your custom color in src/theme/variable.scss like this :

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #8B4789,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  color1: #15c178,
  color2: #8B4789,
  color3 : #07904d,
  color4: #673665,
  brown: #B75E33,
  ycBlue: #638AF1
);
```

> I hope this will work for you

Comment: you are right..

Comment: The same applicable to ion-toolbar

Comment: Great,this is help me

Answer (score 8):

Check [the official docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/navbar/Navbar/).
There is a `color` attribute which takes key from the `$colors` map.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="danger">
    <ion-title>TITLE</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the color like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="danger">
    <ion-title>TITLE</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: ya it helped me thanks